# Uncaught ReferenceError: GridCreated is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am using the telerik RadGrid and populating it from the database, this works fine. I'm working on persisting selecting items through paging & sorting and am using this JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var selected = {};
        function RadGrid1_RowSelected(sender, args) {
            var rfp = args.getDataKeyValue("RFPID");
            if (!selected[rfp]) {
                // alert(rfp);
                selected[rfp] = true;
            }
        }
        function RadGrid1_RowDeselected(sender, args) {
            var rfp = args.getDataKeyValue("RFPID");
            if (selected[rfp]) {
                selected[rfp] = null;
            }
        }
        function RadGrid1_RowCreated(sender, args) {
            var rfp = args.getDataKeyValue("RFPID");
            if (selected[rfp]) {
                args.get_gridDataItem().set_selected(true);
            }
        }
        function GridCreated(sender, eventArgs) {
            var masterTable = sender.get_masterTableView();
            var selectColumn = masterTable.getColumnByUniqueName("RFPIDSelect");
            var headerCheckBox = $(selectColumn.get_element()).find("[type=checkbox]")[0];

            if (headerCheckBox) {
                headerCheckBox.checked = masterTable.get_selectedItems().length ==
                    masterTable.get_dataItems().length;
            }
        }
</script>
```

As you can see **GridCreated** is clearly defined there. It's been called here:

```
<ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true">
    <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" SaveScrollPosition="True"></Scrolling>
    <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
    <ClientEvents OnRowCreated="RadGrid1_RowCreated" OnRowSelected="RadGrid1_RowSelected"
        OnRowDeselected="RadGrid1_RowDeselected" OnGridCreated="GridCreated" />
</ClientSettings>
```

So why am I getting this error when the function is clearly defined?

Comment: have you tried to insert the break point into `RadGrid1_RowSelected()` with chrome and firefox debugger.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't get me any closer to the why of why I'm getting this not declared error on a function that is clearly right there.

Comment: @SumanBogti I added an alert in 'RadGrid1_RowSelected' and it never hits it, why would that be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means a JavaScript guru, but I've worked with it enough to know that it can be a very fickle language. In the past, I've most often seen this kind of issue when there were errors in other JavaScript code above the code where I saw this error. Since JavaScript is interpreted sequentially, if any of the code above this function is throwing an error or has a syntax error, they the "compiler" will fail to see the function and will act as if it isn't there.

Check all your preceding JavaScript code above this for syntax or other issues. You can even temporarily comment out some of it to narrow down on the issue. I realize this may not be the ideal solution, but it usually works for me. :)

Also, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) can be an amazing resource for debugging JavaScript.